# Caliburn.Micro doesn't call my method when SearchBox fires an event

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, caliburn.micro

In my view I have:

```
<SearchBox x:Name="SearchBox" cm:Message.Attach="[Event QuerySubmitted] = [Action Search(SearchBox.QueryText)]" />
```

ViewModel:

```
 public void Search(string query)
 {
     ...
 }
```

But it doesn't call my method. I also tried a long syntax to bind to method but it still not working.

As I noted it doesn't work only with overridden `ISearchBox` events (QueryChanged, QuerySubmitted, etc), but for example for `Tapped` event it works well.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

because the method you created doesn't have the right foot print...

it is expecting signature of

```
public void Search(SearchBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args){

}
```

then your short hand would be

```
[Event QuerySubmitted] = [ Action Search($eventArgs)];
```

I agree it should have worked but sometimes simple events such as a string submit can't be caught, one would think it would.. Also depends on the control too, from what I have seen...

Comment: Created a test app and wired up both ways yours and mine, both work.  So you must have a configuration issue. What version of the framework are you using. win8 or win8.1

Comment: the only thing I see that you don't need is the Convention on the control which is built into the framework in ConventionManager already. Also you can even shorten the event down to cm:Message.Attach="Search(SearchBox.QueryText)"

Comment: actually not, without overriding `UpdateSourceTrigger` for `TextBox` it updates a binding only when loosing focus.

Comment: do you have any binding errors, try turning on the DebugLog

Comment: So does a `SearchBox` in my sample app works well on your pc? Does it call the method in the viewModel?
About `TextBox` I don't know. It works correct for now. Actually I just forgot to delete that code to show you the sample :)